# Validate input to a simple textbox depending on chosen type

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox

I am doing some preparation for my fresher year and I kind of got myself into a mess which I am unable to solve. If you look at the picture below:

[image: This picture]

You can see that I have a text box which I cannot figure out how to make it to accept only certain characters such as 0-7 sans 8 and 9 for octal for example.

Here is my code so far:

```
private void inputBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (hexRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        if (decimalRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) ||  char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
            {                    
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        if (octalRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) ||  char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
            { 
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            e.Handled = false;
        }

        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

I also have tried to do something like this:

```
if (octalRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) ||  char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) || char.IsDigit('7') || char.IsDigit('8'))
```

but that did barely anything.

Comment: You should be able to combine a solution from finding validations for the individual types (dec, hex, etc.) - most likely you will find solutions using regular expression to validate the input. Valdating every single KeyPress char seems very messy. Take the time and search for existing solutions for each type and apply them accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the big problem is here:

```
if (octalRadioButton.Checked)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) ||  char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
    { 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    e.Handled = false; <----------
}
```

After you set it to `true`, you set it to false again... So that's why it allows you to enter invalid chars.

So remove that line.

The second problem is that you are accepting all digits, including 8 and 9. To fix this, I would do something like this:

```
var validChars = new[] {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'};
if (!validChars.Contains(e.KeyChar)) {
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

You can use this approach for other bases as well.

Edit:

Actually, I just looked at the docs, and `Handled` apparently won't work. You need the [SuppressKeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) property, and set that to true in the `KeyDown` event.